# How to shutdown ESXi 5 in N minutes

Tags: vmware-esxi, command-line-interface, busybox

On the VmWare commandline, I can shutdown the box using the `halt` command

```
~ # halt --help
BusyBox v1.9.1-VMware-visor-6030 (2011-02-15 14:57:41 PST) multi-call binary

Usage: halt [-d delay] [-n] [-f]

Halt the system

Options:
        -d      Delay interval for halting
        -n      No call to sync()
        -f      Force halt (don't go through init)
```

Is the delay in minutes (like with the linux shutdown otpion) or in seconds? I could not find this in the docs, I tried googling and did not find the answer. I have no spare vmware box at hand currently to try out by myself.

(I found http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1013193
and also this PDF http://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-50/topic/com.vmware.ICbase/PDF/vsphere-esxi-vcenter-server-50-command-line-management-for-service-console-users.pdflanguage=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1013193 but there was no answer to this in them)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The current source code for busybox halt](http://git.busybox.net/busybox/tree/init/halt.c) indicates the delay is in seconds. If you wanted to test it explicitly, you could run with a delay of 300, and if the system hasn't halted after 5 minutes, you know it's measured in minutes instead of seconds.

Comment: I will try out when I find a good oportunity. I believe they would not change the busybox options in this case.